# Noad steep tv ads running on PC

Tags: virus-removal, malware-removal

I have ads playing in the background of my PC. In the task manager there is a process named noad steep tv. If I try to end it, it just reappears after a few minutes. My antivirus doesn’t find anything. How do I get rid of this virus?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: Try ==>  https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/ 

and ==>  http://www.adlice.com/fr/logiciels/roguekiller/